# Why is my program un-killable?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm debugging a program written by a customer to interface with some hardware my company manufactures using a simple API we supply.    The customer program is a .Net C++ program using Winforms and it's very simple (a Form, a Button and a TextBox) because they were just testing their ability to access our API.

On a 32 bit XP system it runs fine and exits cleanly when I click the "X" in the top right corner of the Form.

On a 64 bit Win 7 system it runs fine but clicking the "X" only closes the Form; it doesn't kill the process.  Furthermore, Task Manager won't kill the process, and puts up no message saying why.   And even in the Command-Prompt window, run as Administrator, when I try to kill it with TaskKill it says, "This process can only be terminated forcefully with a /F option."  So I do that and it says "SUCCESS.  The process with PID 7468 has been terminated."

**Except that it hasn't.**  Both Task Manager and Process Explorer still show it running.   The only way to kill it seems to be to shut down my PC but if I run it again the same thing happens.   How can I debug what makes my program unkillable on Win7/x64?   Thanks!

Comment: ✝ exorcise your computer ✝

Comment: code? Can't say much without seeing it.

Comment: @Dave Almost all the code in it is standard boilerplate that VS generates.   There are about 5 lines of actual customer code for a button handler, and I'm not even pressing the button!   So I suspect this is a build-configuration issue.   But I'll happily post whatever code you think would be helpful.

Comment: is it linked with anything? Is your API included? Are there any static classes / other code which could run at startup, or any functions which run at shutdown? Have you tried recreating the same project from scratch?

Comment: I took Marc's advice and exorcised it.  Specifically I cast away the demon called Avast AntiVirus.  When I did that the problem went away.   I did this because I noticed that Avast was flagging this as a "suspicious program" and putting it in a "sandbox".   Something about being in a "sandbox" seems to make it unkillable.  I don't understand any of this but it would be good to find a way to mark this as "answered" incase anyone else is looking for an answer to this kind of problem.

Comment: You can edit the question to add what you found or just post it as an answer.

Comment: Just turn off Avast's sandbox. It's silly for developers.